# Transform a map of values to a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I am trying to extend my function `toTuple` so that it takes `[(d1, Just x), (d2, Just y), (d3, Just z)]` and produces `[(d1, d2, y), (d2, d3, z)]`

```
import qualified Data.Function.Step.Discrete.Open as SF
import qualified Data.Map as Map

newtype DayMap a = DayMap (SF.SF Day (Maybe a))
  deriving stock (Show, Functor)

toTuple :: Map.Map Day (Maybe a) -> [(Day, Maybe Integer)]
toTuple a = produceList 
    where
      produceList = Map.toList (getDM td3)

getDM :: DayMap a -> Map.Map Day (Maybe a)
getDM (DayMap sf@(SF.SF m hi)) = m

td3 :: DayMap Integer
td3 = DayMap.insert (Just $ fromGregorian 2010 01 01) (Just $ fromGregorian 2012 01 01) 22 DayMap.empty
```

It currently produces this:

```
> toTuple (getDM td3)
[(2010-01-01,Nothing),(2012-01-02,Just 22)]
```

I.e. the value `Just 22` is relevant between `2010-01-01` and `2012-01-02` and is empty before that.

So i want to end up with `[(2010-01-01, 2012-01-02, (Just 22))]` in this case.

I'm not clear on how to extend my `toTuple` function.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens to the `Just x` here?

Comment: It ends up in the tuple between the date preceding it and the date it's originally associated with `[(2010-01-01, 2012-01-02, (Just 22))]`

Comment: Probably something like `zipWith (\(x,_) (y,z) -> (x,y,z)) (tail data) data`.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't follow what's happening with the `(tail data) data` part though.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: `tail` returns the list but without the first element, so that means we zip each item with the next one. So the first item `(x,_)` with the second `(y,z)`; and the second `(x,_)` with the third `(y,z)`; and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process such list with:

```
toTuple :: [(a, b)] -> [(a, a, b)]
toTuple [] = []
toTuple xs@(_:xt) = zipWith f xs xt
    where f (x, _) (y, z) = (x, y, z)
```

Here we thus map an empty list on an empty list. A non-empty list is processed by zipping the list (`xs`) with its tail (`xt`), with as "zipping function" `f`. `f` takes the first item of the "previous" tuple `x`, and the "next" tuple `(y, z)`, and construct a 3-tuple `(x, y, z)`.

Comment: Do you have thoughts on how I might create a helper function that would allow me to supply target start and end `Day`s and truncate the `toTuple` output accordingly?  E.g. if `toTuple` output `[(2010-01-01,2012-01-02,Just 22),(2012-01-02,2013-01-01,Nothing),(2013-01-01,2016-01-02,Just 9)]` and I wanted Days between `2012-06-30` and `2015-01-01`, it should return: `[(2012-06-30,2013-01-01,Nothing),(2013-01-01,2015-01-01,Just 9)]`

Comment: Always bringing excellent answers and a lot of interesting start points to think! awesome work here

Answer (score 0):

The **@Willem Van Onsem** covers everything. I let another version with `foldr` pretty unconventional :

```
toTuple' :: [(a, b)] -> [(a, a, b)]
toTuple' xs = foldr (\_ _ -> zipWith f xs (tail xs)) [] xs
    where f (x, _) (y, z) = (x, y, z)

$> toTuple' [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]

$> [(1,3,4),(3,5,6),(5,7,8)]
```

Comment: I don't think this brings anything to the table. That fold is precisely equivalent to pattern matching on the result of `null xs`, which is clearer.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree and I said that, the accepted answer covered all. But I wanted to put this way also. Thanks for comments and for you time